# PHP DOM: How to get child elements by tag name in an elegant manner?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm parsing some XML with PHP DOM extension in order to store the data in some other form. Quite unsurprisingly, when I parse an element I pretty often need to obtain all children elements of some name. There is the method `DOMElement::getElementsByTagName($name)`, but it returns all descendants with that name, not just immediate children. There is also the property `DOMNode::$childNodes` but (1) it contains node list, not element list, and even if I managed to turn the list items into elements (2) I'd still need to check all of them for the name. Is there really no elegant solution to get only the children of some specific name or am I missing something in the documentation?

Some illustration:

```
<?php

DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(<<<EndOfXML
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <b>2</b>
  <c>
    <b>3</b>
    <b>4</b>
  </c>
</a>
EndOfXML
);

$bs = $document
    ->getElementsByTagName('a')
    ->item(0)
    ->getElementsByTagName('b');

foreach($bs as $b){
    echo $b->nodeValue . "\n";
}

// Returns:
//   1
//   2
//   3
//   4
// I'd like to obtain only:
//   1
//   2

?>
```

Comment: OTOH, just run a `DOMXPath::query` with a context node. (or add the whole document, and query for `/a[1]/b`)

Comment: In real life I parse quite big files, so I use `DOMReader` and it's method `expand()` to parse them chunk by chunk. Unfortunately, the side effect is I have no `DOMDocument`, only many instances of `DOMElement` and I cannot elegantly construct `DOMXPAth` for them... Why is it all so poorly thought out!?! I wanted to avoid conversion of `DOMElment`s again into `SimpleXML`, but I'm closer and closer to this decision...

Answer (score 11):

simple iteration process

```
$parent = $p->parentNode;

foreach ( $parent->childNodes as $pp ) {

    if ( $pp->nodeName == 'p' ) {

        if ( strlen( $pp->nodeValue ) ) {
            echo "{$pp->nodeValue}\n";
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

An elegant manner I can imagine would be using a `FilterIterator` that is suitable for the job. Exemplary one that is able to work on such a said `DOMNodeList` and (optionally) accepting a tagname to filter for as an exemplary `DOMElementFilter` from the *Iterator Garden*  does:

```
$a = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);

$bs = new DOMElementFilter($a->childNodes, 'b');

foreach($bs as $b){
    echo $b->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

This will give the results you're looking for:

```
1
2
```

You can find [`DOMElementFilter` in the Development branch](https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden/blob/development/src/DOM/DOMElementFilter.php) now. It's perhaps worth to allow `*` for any tagname as it's possible with `getElementsByTagName("*")` as well. But that's just some commentary.

Hier is a working usage example online: https://eval.in/57170

Answer (score -1):

My solution used in a production:

**Finds a needle (node) in a haystack (DOM)**

```
function getAttachableNodeByAttributeName(\DOMElement $parent = null, string $elementTagName = null, string $attributeName = null, string $attributeValue = null)
{
    $returnNode = null;

    $needleDOMNode = $parent->getElementsByTagName($elementTagName);

    $length = $needleDOMNode->length;
    //traverse through each existing given node object
    for ($i = $length; --$i >= 0;) {

        $needle = $needleDOMNode->item($i);

        //only one DOM node and no attributes specified?
        if (!$attributeName && !$attributeValue && 1 === $length) return $needle;
        //multiple nodes and attributes are specified
        elseif ($attributeName && $attributeValue && $needle->getAttribute($attributeName) === $attributeValue) return $needle;
    }

    return $returnNode;
}
```

Usage:

```
$countryNode = getAttachableNodeByAttributeName($countriesNode, 'country', 'iso', 'NL');
```

Returns DOM element from parent countries node by specified attribute `iso` using country ISO code 'NL', basically like a real search would do. Find a certain country by it's name in an array / object.

Another usage example:

```
$productNode = getAttachableNodeByAttributeName($products, 'partner-products');
```

Returns DOM node element containing only single (root) node, without searching by any attribute. 
Note: for this you must make sure that root nodes are unique by elements' tag name, e.g. `countries->country[ISO]` - `countries` node here is unique and parent to all child nodes.