# PHP appendChild to XML root

Tags: php, xml, appendchild

I know this should be simple, but I'm new to PHP and just do not understand the documentation I've come across. I need a simple explanation.

I have an XML document that I would like to add nodes to. I can add nodes to the document, they only appear outside of the root node and cause errors to happen on subsequent attempts.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
</root>
```

and here is my PHP:

```
$playerID = "id_" . $_POST['player'];

//load xml file to edit
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('../../saves/playerPositions.xml') or die("Error: Cannot load file.");

//check if the player is already in the database
if(isset($xlm->$playerID)){
    echo "Player ID was found.";
}
else{
    echo "Player ID was not found.";

    //so we want to create a new node with this player information
    $playerElement = $xml->createElement($playerID, "");
    $playerName = $xml->createElement("name", "John Doe");

    //add the name to the playerElement
    $playerElement->appendChild($playerName);

    //add the playerElement to the document
    //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
    $xml->root->appendChild($playerElement);

    //save and close the document
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->save("../../saves/playerPositions.xml");
}

echo "done";
```

If I just use `$xml->appendChild()` then I can modify the document, but the new text appears outside of `<root></root>`.

The exact error is:

> Notice: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$root

Comment: Which one do you have in your actual code, `$xml->root->...` or `$xml->$root->...` ?

Comment: If I use $xml->root->appendChild() then the error is DOMDocument::$root
If I use $xml->$root->appendChild() then the error is DOMDocument::root

But I am using "root" as I understand that to be the more correct way of doing it. The OP is my exact code.

Comment: Ok, but the error message doesn't correspond to the code, hence it is confusing. The error message that I got with `$xml->root` : *Fatal error: Call to a member function `appendChild()` on `null`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$xml->root` isn't the correct way to access root element in this context, since `$xml` is an instance of `DOMDocument` (It will work if `$xml` were `SimpleXMLElement` instead). You can get root element of a `DOMDocument` object from `documentElement` property :

```
$xml->documentElement->appendChild($playerElement);
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo 1`](https://eval.in/653695)</kbd>**

Or, more generally, you can get element by name using `getElementsByTagName()` :

```
$xml->getElementsByTagName("root")->item(0)->appendChild($playerElement);
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo 2`](https://eval.in/653690)</kbd>**

Further reading : [PHP DOM: How to get child elements by tag name in an elegant manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555054/php-dom-how-to-get-child-elements-by-tag-name-in-an-elegant-manner)

---

That said, this part of your code is also not correct for the same reason (plus a typo?):

```
if(isset($xlm->$playerID)){
    echo "Player ID was found.";
}
```

Replace with `getElementsByTagName()` :

```
if($xml->getElementsByTagName($playerID)->length > 0){
    echo "Player ID was found.";
}
```

Comment: When I started the code I was trying to use the SimpleXMLElement and couldn't get it to read the file. I ended up with the DOMDocument, not realizing it was a different structure. 

Though this syntax is longer, I'm more comfortable with it because it is like JavaScript and XML. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to handle the dom like a Standar Object, but is not.
To look for elements, you need to use the function getElementsByTagName, and handle the dom like a collection of nodes, like this:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
</root>') or die("Error: Cannot load file.");

    $len = $xml->getElementsByTagName('player')->length;
    if ( $len > 0 ) {

    } else {
      $player = $xml->createElement('player', '');
      $playerName = $xml->createElement('playerName', "Jhon Doe");
      $player->appendChild( $playerName );

      $root = $xml->getElementsByTagName('root');

      if ( $root->length > 0 ) {
        $root[0]->appendChild( $player );
      }

      $xml->formatOutput = true;
      echo $xml->saveXML();
    }
```

This code produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<player><playerName>Jhon Doe</playerName></player></root>
```